# Python Pandas, move string in cell one to the right if right column NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a script in Excel which cleans data for a phone number contact list, which I am trying to convert into Python.

I have figured out how spaces are removed, but what I am struggling with is getting data moved into the correct position. Below is an example of the data which comes across in a spreadsheet, and what I want to achieve is to move the mobile number in the phone column across to the Mobile phone column, it also needs to remove the row is the Mobile Phone column is NaN and the Phone Column is not a mobile number. The reason for this is because it is for a mobile number only list, and to know the difference is based on the first two characters of the number so if 07 keep else remove.

[image]

So what I want to achieve is the following:

[image]

Below is the code I have so far, I can replace the NaN with a 0 but I can't shift a cell across.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlrd as xlrd

UsrName = input(print("Please enter the path of the excel file "))

df = pd.read_excel(UsrName)


# This cleans up the spaces etc
Data = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if x.dtype == "object" else x)
Data['Mobile Phone'] = Data['Mobile Phone'].str.replace(" ","")
Data["Phone"] = Data["Phone"].str.replace(" ","")
#This now shifts empty phone numbers
Data['Mobile Phone'] = Data['Mobile Phone'].replace(np.NaN,0)

print(Data)
```

Comment: Please dont send images. Try `df['Mobile Phone']=df['Mobile Phone'].mask(df['Mobile Phone'].isna(),df['Phone'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it also needs to remove the row is the Mobile Phone column is NaN and the Phone Column is not a mobile number

I'm not quite sure what the parameters would be for determining if 'Phone' is not a mobile number. I can see that the 'Frank' row was dropped in the example, but I'm not entirely sure why.

As far as transferring data from the 'Phone' column to the 'Mobile Phone' column, this should work:
**Edit:**
Added a line for filtering non-phone numbers from the 'Phone' column.

```
df = df[(df['Phone'].str.startswith('07',na=False))|(df['Mobile Phone'].notna())]
df['Mobile Phone'] = np.where(((df['Mobile Phone'].isna())&(df['Phone'].notna())),df['Phone'],df['Mobile Phone'])
```

Comment: Just updated my post, its basically to get mobile numbers only and so as long as the first two numbers are 07 it's ok else remove

Comment: @Kyoujin I updated the answer with the additional line to remove non-phone # lines.